# py2exe - generate single installer file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, py2exe

I use python2.7, py2exe, pyqt4 and want to generate a installer file just like dropbox . This is my setup.py file

```
# coding=utf8

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')
py2exe_options = {
    "includes": ["sip",'encodings', 'encodings.*'],
    "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll", 'OLEAUT32.dll', 'USER32.dll', 'IMM32.dll', 'SHELL32.dll', 'ole32.dll', 'WINMM.dll', 'USER32.dll', 'EKRNEL32.dll', 'ADVAPI32.dll', 'COMDLG32.dll', 'WS2_32.dll', 'WINSPOOL.DRV', 'GDI32.dll', 'KERNEL32.dll'],
    "compressed": 1,
    "optimize": 2,
    "ascii": 0,
    "bundle_files": 1
}

setup(
    name='IP',
    version='1.0',
    zipfile = None,
    windows=["main.py"],
    options={'py2exe': py2exe_options}
)
```

I want to generate install by running 'python setup.py py2exe', but failed.
How do i do next to generate installer ?

Answer (score 1):

Which do you want? a `Single Executive File` or a `Installer`?
Your code seems to pack all the code in one file.

If you want a `Installer`, you can pass that `Single Executive File` to some program like **[Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)**, to generate a Installer.